# Join Multiple Querysets From Different Base Models Django

Tags: django, join, concatenation, django-queryset

I currently have two different models.

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    from_account = models.ForeignKey(Account,related_name='transferred_from')
    to_account = models.ForeignKey(Account,related_name='transferred_to')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    memo = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)

class Ledger(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    bank_account = models.ForeignKey(EquityAccount,related_name='paid_from')
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Party)
    memo = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
```

I am creating a report in a view and get the following error:
Merging 'ValuesQuerySet' classes must involve the same values in each case.

What I'm trying to do is only pull out the fields that are common so I can concatenate both of them e.g.

```
def report(request):

    ledger = GeneralLedger.objects.values('account').annotate(total=Sum('amount'))
    journal = Journal.objects.values('from_account').annotate(total=Sum('amount'))
    report = ledger & journal
...
```

If I try to make them exactly the same to test e.g.

```
def report(request):

    ledger = GeneralLedger.objects.values('memo').annotate(total=Sum('amount'))
    journal = Journal.objects.values('memo').annotate(total=Sum('amount'))
    report = ledger & journal
...
```

I get this error:
Cannot combine queries on two different base models.

Anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
report = chain(ledger, journal)
```

[Itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) for the win!

If you want to do an Union, you should convert these `querysets` into python `set` objects.

If it is possible to filter the queryset itself rightly, you should really do that!

Comment: I'm getting this:

AttributeError: 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'model'

Answer (score 8):

Use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
report = list(chain(ledger, journal))
```

Note: you need to turn the resulting object into a list for Django to be able to process it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I solved it using the [union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#union) method `combined_queryset = qs1.union(qs2)`

Using your example: `report = ledger.union(journal)`