# How can I join three Django Models to return a queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I want to create a queryset that references three related models, and allows me to filter. The SQL might look like this:

```
SELECT th.id, th.customer, ft.filename, fva.path
FROM TransactionHistory th
LEFT JOIN FileTrack ft
  ON th.InboundFileTrackID = ft.id
LEFT JOIN FileViewArchive fva
  ON fva.FileTrackId = ft.id
WHERE th.customer = 'ACME, Inc.'
-- AND ft.filename like '%storage%' --currently don't need to do this, but seeing placeholder logic would be nice
```

I have three models in Django, shown below.  It's a bit tricky, because the TransactionHistory model has two foreign keys to the same model (FileTrack).  And FileViewArchive has a foreign key to FileTrack.

```
class FileTrack(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(db_column="id", primary_key=True)
    filename = models.CharField(db_column="filename", max_length=128)

    class Meta:
          managed = False
          db_table = "FileTrack"  

class TransactionHistory(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(db_column="id", primary_key=True)
    customer = models.CharField(db_column="Customer", max_length=128)
    inbound_file_track = models.ForeignKey(
            FileTrack,
            db_column="InboundFileTrackId",
            related_name="inbound_file_track_id",
            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
            null=True,
    )
    outbound_file_track = models.ForeignKey(
            FileTrack,
            db_column="OutboundFileTrackId",
            related_name="outbound_file_track_id",  
            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
            null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "TransactionHistory"

class FileViewArchive(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(db_column="id", primary_key=True)
    file_track = models.ForeignKey(
            FileTrack,
            db_column="FileTrackId",
            related_name="file_track_id",
            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
            null=True,
    )
    path = models.CharField(db_column="Path", max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "FileViewArchive"
```

One thing I tried:

```
qs1 = TransactionHistory.objects.select_related('inbound_file_track').filter(customer='ACME, Inc.')
qs2 = FileViewArchive.objects.select_related('file_track').all()
qs = qs1 & qs2  # doesn't work b/c they are different base models
```

And [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6732451/4686075) to use chain doesn't work either because it's sending two separate queries an I'm not altogether sure if/how it's merging them.  I'm looking for a single query in order to be more performant.  Also it returns an iterable, so I'm not sure I can use this in my view (Django Rest Framework).  Lastly x below returns a TransactionHistory object, so I can't even access the fields from the other two models.

```
from itertools import chain
c = chain(qs1 | qs2)  # great that his this lazy and doesn't evaluate until used! 
type(c) # this returns <class 'itertools.chain'> and it doesn't consolidate 
x = list(c)[0] # runs two separate queries
type(x) # a TransactionHistory object -> so no access to the Filetrack or FileViewArchive fields
```

Any ideas how I can join three models together?  Something like this?:

```
qs = TransactionHistory.objects.select_related('inbound_file_track').select_related('file_track').filter(customer='ACME, Inc.', file_track__filename__contains='storage')
```

More info: this is part of a view that will look like below. It returns a querysets that is used as part of a Django Rest Framework view.

```
class Transaction(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        query_params = self.request.query_params.copy()
        company = query_params.pop("company", [])[0]
        filename = query_params.pop("filename", [])[0]

        # need code here that generate filtered queryset for filename and company
        # qs = TransactionHistory.objects.select_related('inbound_file_track').select_related('file_track').filter(customer='ACME, Inc.', file_track__filename__contains='storage')

        return qs.order_by("id")
```

Comment: Can you share what output you are expecting?

Comment: I'd like to return a filtered viewset. I'll add to the question, thanks!

Comment: Based from the sql query you shared,  you are filtering based on the `inbound_file_track` file name. So something like this should work:
`TransactionHistory.objects.select_related('inbound_file_track').prefetch_related('inbound_file_track__file_track_id').filter(customer='ACME, Inc.', inbound_file_track___filename__contains='storage')`

Comment: @BrianDestura, yes that worked, thanks!  Do you you want to create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome! I've posted this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from the sql query you shared, you are filtering based on the `inbound_file_track` file name. So something like this should work:

```py
TransactionHistory.objects.select_related(
    'inbound_file_track',
).prefetch_related(
    'inbound_file_track__file_track_id',
).filter(
    customer='ACME, Inc.', inbound_file_track___filename__contains='storage',
)
```